# How to tell MAMP which version of PHP to use?

Tags: php, version, mamp, pecl

I've installed PECL for PHP on MAMP. Unfortunately, it is using php 5.3.6 which is different form the most recent version of PHP(which is 5.4.10 today). When looking a phpinfo, I see that it is not loading the php.ini file I want (5.3.6), it is loading the latest one (which is normal)

How to tell MAMP which version of PHP to use ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you in this case ? http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16801

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check your Prefences pane. Should you want specific versions, you will need to install them manually or [take a look at this thread](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16801).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, the PHP version I'm looking for is not listed there. How to fix that ? I've been checking your link, it doesn't describe a solution for what I'm loking to do

Comment: Check the downloads page. http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html - I think you need MAMP Pro. Unless you want to fiddle with your `Applications/MAMP/bin/php` folder.

Answer (score 1):

**1** - [Download the desired version of PHP here (listed on the right)](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/).

**2** - Two cases:

Either you have **Mamp pro** and you can change it through the user interface or you have **the free version of Mamp** and can achieve that, renaming each folder with for example `.DIS` at the end at `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/` and just not renaming any version of php, plus the one that you are going to import and consequently copy-paste. This is because **the free version of Mamp** only allows you to see the two highest version of php through the user interface ([for more information watch this video tutorial which will give you more details about the process to follow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHXwUXnq3Zw)).